# Summon Latex-Suite \cite autocompletion in macro

Tags: vim, csquotes, vim-latex

Latex-Suite lets me autocomplete keys in `\cite{}` (and other similar commands like `\parencite{}` ou `\citet{}`) with <kbd>F9</kbd>. This is useful, but I'm using the csquotes package which offers commands like `\blockcquote[][]{}[]{}`.

I've written macros in my tex.vim file for many of these commands. They are working nicely, but I would like to be able to use the autocomplete function for some of them using citation keys to act like the `\cite{}` command. For now, the blockcquote macro for example looks like this :

```
 :call IMAP('blockcquote', '\blockcquote[<+prenote+>][<+postnote+>]{<+key+>}[<+punct+>]{<+text+>}<++>', 'tex')
```

Is this possible or does a workaround exist?